# Does having the IIS log header in the log file mean that IIS was reset during the day?

Tags: iis, logging

When I'm viewing IIS log files I can see various times during the day where the header line is written out to the log file. The only time I've seen this is happening is when IIS resets; or starts up.
For example the header line below;

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 6.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2010-10-18 07:28:06
#Fields: date time s-sitename s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status
```

The customer is saying there is no IIS resets happening; but does this entry in the log file mean that IIS was definitely reset for some reason which may be outside of the customers control.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually figured in out in the wee hours of the morning. If you have W3C logging enabled for different web sites/services, but have different fields configured for those web sites/services then when site1 is hit it output the list of fields and later on when site2 is hit it appends any different fields onto the list of the 1st fields and outputs the combined set of fields.

So having multiple sets of the # directives in the log file does not necessarily means that IIS was reset.

Comment: This is a great answer, do you have any references to documentation on this?

Comment: Sorry Alex, no documentation references, this is purely from manual observation of the behaviours in these circumstances.

Comment: @Bigtoe: The thread here http://forums.iis.net/t/1172464.aspx appears to cover the issue above but an extra comment has been added suggesting the IIS header is being caused by the app pool recycling. Could you confirm your latest view on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to **Dean Cron** (*Microsoft engineer working in IIS team*) the logging headers are re-written on:

1. IIS reset
2. Server reboot
3. App Pool recycling
4. If you've added or removed one or more logging fields in the logging configuration.
5. If a site doesn't receive requests for a set period of time (15 minutes), the handle to the associated log file is closed. The next time a request comes in, the log file is re-opened and the log headers written.

You can find more details in [Dean's blog post](https://blogs.iis.net/deanc/iis-log-faq-logging-headers).

So no, the header appearing in the log file **does not** mean that IIS was reset.